# Ionic apps in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to build a cordova/ionic app in visual studio 2015. I have loaded the ionic & cordova extensions. I have installed Node. When i create the template for an ionic app, none of the ion tags in the html file are recognised. 
e.g. both of these are not recognised

```
<body ng-app="starter">

<ion-nav-back-button>
```

After much searching i also have noticed that i don't have a _references.js file. I created the file but i don't get the auto sync option.

Have i missed a reference in my setup?

Comment: When you run the application, does it appear OK? Are you referring to IntelliSense suggestions in the code editors? Also - what version of Visual Studio 2015 are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Did you create your ionic project from an existing VS template? That could help you avoid any missing parts that you forgot to manually install. The first few steps of this guide can show you how to add these ionic templates to VS: http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-ionic/

Comment: Also you don't need your own version of Node--VS Cordova comes with a sandboxed version.